# How can i implement from this ERD to this EERD? (in oracle)

Tags: oracle, model, entity, implementation, erd

I got a few Person's they are named "Patient","Mitarbeiter" and "Arzt" .
After that i got a Superclass for them named "Person".
But i cannot implement it because of the foreign keys.

I tried much things but forgot it now.

Fehler beim Start in Zeile: 133 in Befehl -
ALTER TABLE Mitarbeiter ADD FOREIGN KEY (Praxis_ID) REFERENCES Praxis (Praxis_ID)
Fehlerbericht -
ORA-00904: "PRAXIS_ID": ungültiger Bezeichner
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

i get this error.. that i cannot alter the table for a foreign key

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Person AS OBJECT (
    P_ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR2(50),
    Vorname VARCHAR2(50),
    Geburtsdatum DATE,
    Telefonnummer VARCHAR2(50),
    Strasse VARCHAR2(50),
    Ort VARCHAR2(50),
    PLZ VARCHAR2(50),
    Email VARCHAR2(50),
    Passwort VARCHAR2(50)
    );

Comment: CREATE TABLE Mitarbeiter OF Person(
P_ID  PRIMARY KEY
);

Comment: ALTER TABLE Mitarbeiter ADD FOREIGN KEY (Praxis_ID) REFERENCES Praxis (Praxis_ID);

Comment: https://ibb.co/VVKSfQz thats the ERD

Comment: and that is the EERD but i cannot implement the eerd..

Comment: You can [edit] your question if you want to add something. Don't use comments for that.